# how is UPDATE in Nestjs typeorm (pgsql) works?

Tags: sql, save, nestjs, typeorm

In service.ts file

```js
......
import { Repository } from "typeorm";
....
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Profile)
    private readonly profileRepository: Repository<Profile>,
  )......

async updateprofile(profile_id:string, data: any): Promise<any> {
    try {
      console.log(profile_id);
      await this.profileRepository.update(data); //how to update without saving new row in db

      return {
        success: true,
        message: 'Successfully updated profile',
      };
    } catch (err) {}}....
```

i don't know how to update using particular  id and body data without save.(This update syntax is wrong)
because when save is used it make two rows which have unique values so error.
and console.log(id) is giving output

```
{ profile_id: '29adb514-a10f-49c0-bde2-19dcbcf9e0b9' }
```

how to take value of that too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already `profile_id` is an object and not a string.

Then, to modify the profile and not add a line in the DB, you just have to proceed as follows:

```js
import { Repository } from "typeorm";
....

constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Profile)
    private readonly profileRepository: Repository<Profile>,
  ){}

async updateprofile(dto: { profile_id: string }, data: any): Promise<any> {
    try {
      console.log(dto);
      await this.profileRepository.update(dto.profile_id, data); 

      return {
        success: true,
        message: 'Successfully updated profile',
      };
    } catch (err) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: okey, I think this would work, because I got a error in controller because i dont know what the type should give in parameters of function for --- dto: { profile_id: string }